# Wordpress custom options not being saved

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having problems with adding a custom settings page for wordpress, and more specifically getting the options to save.

The documentation for this seems to be lacking and inconsistent, as different examples and different different functions explain the same thing differently.

The newest example on the wordpress codex uses the sanitize callback function to save options. But the add_settings_field() documentation says that saving the options should happen behind the scenes. Seems wierd to use san callback to save anyways.

I have tried various different approaches, and at one time my code managed to save one of the fields but not all of them.

My current code:

```
class wwtkSettings {
    public function __construct() {
        if ( is_admin() ){
            add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
        }
    }

    public function add_plugin_page(){
        add_options_page( 'WWTK Settings', 'WWTK settings', 'manage_options', 'wwtk-settings', array( $this, 'create_admin_page' ) );
    }

    public function create_admin_page() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <?php screen_icon(); ?>
            <h2>WWTK Settings</h2>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php
                settings_fields( 'wwtk-setting-group' );
                do_settings_sections( 'wwtk-settings' );
                ?>
                <?php submit_button(); ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    public function page_init() {
        register_setting( 'wwtk-setting-group', 'wwtk-setting-group', array( $this, 'wwtk_validate_options' ) );

        add_settings_section(
            'wwtk-settings-section',
            'Categories and pages',
            array( $this, 'print_section_info' ),
            'wwtk-settings'
            );  

        add_settings_field(
            'frontpage', 
            'Frontpage category:', 
            array( $this, 'create_category_field' ), 
            'wwtk-settings',
            'wwtk-settings-section',
            'frontpage'
            );
        add_settings_field(
            'category1', 
            'Category & page 1', 
            array( $this, 'create_category_field' ), 
            'wwtk-settings',
            'wwtk-settings-section',
            'category1'
            );
        add_settings_field(
            'category2', 
            'Category & page 2', 
            array( $this, 'create_category_field' ), 
            'wwtk-settings',
            'wwtk-settings-section',
            'category2'
            );
        add_settings_field(
            'category3', 
            'Category & page 3', 
            array( $this, 'create_category_field' ), 
            'wwtk-settings',
            'wwtk-settings-section',
            'category3'
            );
    }

    //TODO: check if category and page exist. and sanitize!
    public function wwtk_validate_options( $input ) {
        return $input;
    }

    public function print_section_info(){
        print 'Enter the names of categories that should be displayed on the page with the same name(both must exist):';
    }

    public function create_category_field($args){
        ?><input type="text" id="<?php echo $args ?>" name="wwtk-setting-group" value="<?php echo get_option( 'wwtk-setting-group['.$args.']' ); ?>" /><?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this all the code for your plugin? I'm working on a solution for you but want to make sure that I have all the necessary code to help ;)

Comment: This is for a custom theme, and except for adding nav menues and adding support for thumbnails this is the entire functions.php.
Thank you so much for trying to help:)

Comment: The point is to utilize the saved options for displaying posts of a particular type on each page. I wanted to experiment with different approaches, but got stuck when trying to save more than one custom option.

Comment: How and when are you calling the class? Also inside your functions.php file? Typically you would create and setup the pages outside of a class and then have all your options inside a class.

Comment: Yes the class is being instantiated inside functions.php
$wwtkSettings = new wwtkSettings();
The way the code has been structured is pr. this example: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/* code similar to your example */

class MySettingsPage{
/**
 * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
 */
private $options;

/**
 * Start up
 */
public function __construct()
{
    add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
}

/**
 * Add options page
 */
public function add_plugin_page()
{
    // This page will be under "Settings"
    add_options_page(
        'Settings Admin', 
        'My Settings', 
        'manage_options', 
        'my-setting-admin', 
        array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
    );
}

/**
 * Options page callback
 */
public function create_admin_page()
{
    // Set class property
    $this->options = get_option( 'my_option_name' );
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php screen_icon(); ?>
        <h2>My Settings</h2>           
        <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php
            // This prints out all hidden setting fields
            settings_fields( 'my_option_group' );   
            do_settings_sections( 'my-setting-admin' );
            submit_button(); 
        ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Register and add settings
 */
public function page_init()
{        
    register_setting(
        'my_option_group', // Option group
        'my_option_name', // Option name
        array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
    );

    add_settings_section(
        'setting_section_id', // ID
        'My Custom Settings', // Title
        array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
        'my-setting-admin' // Page
    );  

    add_settings_field(
        'id_number', // ID
        'ID Number', // Title 
        array( $this, 'id_number_callback' ), // Callback
        'my-setting-admin', // Page
        'setting_section_id' // Section           
    );      

    add_settings_field(
        'title', 
        'Title', 
        array( $this, 'title_callback' ), 
        'my-setting-admin', 
        'setting_section_id'
    );      
}

/**
 * Sanitize each setting field as needed
 *
 * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
 */
public function sanitize( $input )
{
    if( !is_numeric( $input['id_number'] ) )
        $input['id_number'] = '';  

    if( !empty( $input['title'] ) )
        $input['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['title'] );

    return $input;
}

/** 
 * Print the Section text
 */
public function print_section_info()
{
    print 'Enter your settings below:';
}

/** 
 * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
 */
public function id_number_callback()
{
    printf(
        '<input type="text" id="id_number" name="my_option_name[id_number]" value="%s" />',
        esc_attr( $this->options['id_number'])
    );
}

/** 
 * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
 */
 public function title_callback()
 {
    printf(
        '<input type="text" id="title" name="my_option_name[title]" value="%s" />',
        esc_attr( $this->options['title'])
    );
 }
}

if( is_admin() )
    $my_settings_page = new MySettingsPage();
```

Comment: Clever solution instead of using `update_option_{$option_name}` hook. I had conflict to use it.